# google apps script sending mail with n- attachments

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to find anything that would accomplish what I'm trying to do, and I'm not as proficient in JavaScript as I would like to be, so please bear with me...
As I mentioned in the title, I'm writing this in google apps script...

If I have a code something like:

```js
function getMails() {
  // get the first 5 threads
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);
  // get all the messages for the threads selected
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  // iterate through the threads
  // ('messages' being the first message of the thread)
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    // then iterate through every message of the thread

    var blobs = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {
      // create a blob for every message
      var blob = Utilities.newBlob(messages[i][j].getRawContent(),
        'text/plain',
        'message' + j + '.eml');
      // push the blob into the array
      blobs.push(blob);
    }
    // here's where I think I'm having trouble finding a solution
    // and I do not want to zip all the blobbed messages into 1
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      "thread report: [" + messages[i][0].getSubject() + "]",
      "attached message as text/plain", {
        name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
        attachments: blobs
      });
  }
}
```

would anybody please give me a pointer on how I could accomplish this last step for a variable number of messages per thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to be working?" Are emails sending? Is _any_thing attached? If so, are they plaintext files? You need to add some details.

Comment: Can we ask you about ``content`` of ``Utilities.newBlob(content, 'text/plain', 'message' + j + '.eml')``?

Comment: @Robi GoogleAppScript has a logger feature -- try enabling and using that so you can get more information about what's not working

Comment: In your script, the length of ``blobs`` is continued to increase. If you want to use each blob for each mail, please put ``blobs = []`` to before ``for (var j = 0; j < messages[i].length; j++) {`` inside ``for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {``.

Comment: @Brian: the emails were sending, but I kept getting an error about a mismatch of parameters for attachments, and the emails arrived empty without attachments.

Comment: @Tanaike: sorry, 'content' was the rawContent from the message. I edited and corrected the code, and thanks for catching the growth of blobs[] !

Comment: @duhaime: I've been using the Logger.log feature, but couldn't figure out why it wasn't working for me, but thanks to all of your comments and insights and a little bit of more thinking and trying, I finally got it to work as intended. Thank you all!

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved.

Comment: @Robi: The solution should be posted as an answer. Ref. [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Rubén: I understand what you  mean, but I do not really have a solution/answer to my question, as I still do not understand why my code was giving me the errors and sending the blank emails. all I can say, is that with the insight of the commenters and my rewriting parts of the code, it just worked. My apologies for not being able to post an answer unless this is the answer, but in MNSHO it doesn't qualify as a valid answer, and just copying and pasting the above code doesn't seem the right way...

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments and re-trying the code (and fixing some things that I had missed because I wrote it on the fly and didn't copy and paste my working/non-working code) I got it to work! Thank you all for your help with your comments and insights. The code in the question is edited and is working as intended.